# Is It possible in Java code to run grand permission SQL from the MySQL client?

Tags: java, mysql, remote-access

Provided we know the remote MySQL username and password.

Is it possible to run (in Java code)

```
grant all on *.* TO root@'192.168.1.61' identified by 'password';
```

in remote client to the remote mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the account that connects to the mysql server has the correct permissions to issue a statement like this everything should work properly.